# Edit names of columns with Regex and gsub

Tags: r

I want to remove two substrings (`_x` and `_y`) from the column names of a data frame and replace them with `L_` and `H_`; the replacments are to be placed at the beginning of the column names.

Input :

```
colnames(df)
[1] "UMI_Codes"             "SEQUENCE_ID_x"        "SEQUENCE_INPUT_x"     "FUNCTIONAL_x"        
  [5] "IN_FRAME_x"           "STOP_x"               "MUTATED_INVARIANT_x"  "INDELS_x"            
  [9] "LOCUS_x"              "V_CALL_y"             "D_CALL_y"             "J_CALL_y"
```

What I have tried so far:

```
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="SEQUENCE_ID_x"] <- "L_SEQUENCE_ID"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="SEQUENCE_INPUT_x"] <- "L_SEQUENCE_INPUT"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="FUNCTIONAL_x"] <- "L_FUNCTIONAL"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="IN_FRAME_x"] <- "L_IN_FRAME"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="STOP_x"] <- "L_STOP"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="MUTATED_INVARIANT_x"] <- "L_MUTATED_INVARIANT"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="INDELS_x"] <- "L_INDELS"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="LOCUS_x"] <- "L_LOCUS"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="V_CALL_y"] <- "H_V_CALL"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="D_CALL_y"] <- "H_D_CALL"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="J_CALL_y"] <- "H_J_CALL"
```

Out put :

```
[1] "UMI_Codes"             "L_SEQUENCE_ID"        "L_SEQUENCE_INPUT"     "L_FUNCTIONAL"        
  [5] "L_IN_FRAME"           "L_STOP"               "L_MUTATED_INVARIANT"  "L_INDELS"            
  [9] "L_LOCUS_"              "H_V_CALL"             "H_D_CALL"             "H_J_CALL"
```

This works but I'd prefer to make the changes in a single line of code. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see from your question is that you have two types of columnnames, one ending in `_x`and one ending in `_y` and you want to remove both endings and replace with string-initial `L_`and, respectively, `H_`. If that's correct then this should do the trick:

```
df <- data.frame(
  SEQUENCE_ID_x = letters[1:5],
  V_CALL_y = LETTERS[1:5]
)

sub("(.*?)_x", "L_\\1", sub("(.*?)_y", "H_\\1", names(df)))
[1] "L_SEQUENCE_ID" "H_V_CALL"
```

This is a nested `sub`operation, i.e., the result of the second `sub`operation (`sub("(.*?)_y", "H_\\1", names(df))`) is used as input for the first `sub` operation. Moreover, the two operations use *backreference* in `\\1` (in the replacement argument of `sub`). The backreference 'recollects', as it were, the exact string found, in this case, prior to the substrings `_x`and, respectively, `_y`.

To actually save this to your `df`:

```
names(df) <- sub("(.*?)_x", "L_\\1", sub("(.*?)_y", "H_\\1", names(df)))
df
  L_SEQUENCE_ID H_V_CALL
1             a        A
2             b        B
3             c        C
4             d        D
5             e        E
```

Comment: it's working well. By the way, what do this scripts doing?      (.*?)

Comment: Have added an explanation to the answer.